# Помогите с rowspan и colspan в html таблице

Tags: html

Как сделать расположение ячеек XPATH/XSL, что бы первый стобец был общий, второй и третий делились на 3 строчки, а четвёртый на 2?

[image: Таблица, которую нужно сверстать]

Comment: непонятна суть вопроса
Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Я понял вопрос, сейчас попробую рассказать

Comment: Что не понятно в xsl?

Comment: @Yuri, если поняли, о чём вопрос, внесите в него, пожалуйста, правки, чтобы, во-первых, это поняли и другие, а во-вторых, чтобы вопрос и ответ были полезны ещё кому-нибудь помимо автора вопроса. для этого, в частности, следует заменить картинку текстом.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вот так это делается :)

```css
th {text-align:center;}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr><th rowspan="3">Day</th><th colspan="3">Seminar</th></tr>
    <tr><th colspan="2">Schedule</th><th rowspan="2">Topie</th></tr>
    <tr><th>Begin</th><th>End</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td rowspan="2">Monday</td><td rowspan="2">8:00 a.m.</td><td rowspan="2">5:00 p.m.</td><td>Introduction to XML</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td></tr>
    <tr><td rowspan="6">Tuesday</td><td rowspan="2">8:00 a.m.</td><td rowspan="2">11:00 a.m.</td><td rowspan="3">XPath</td></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr><td rowspan="2">11:00 a.m.</td><td rowspan="2">2:00 p.m.</td></tr>
    <tr><td rowspan="3">XSL Transformations</td></tr>
    <tr><td rowspan="2">2:00 a.m.</td><td rowspan="2">5:00 p.m.</td></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr><td>Wednasday</td><td>8:00 a.m.</td><td>12:00 p.m.</td><td>XSL Formatting Objects</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: А если вопрос по xsl?

Comment: @nick_n_a, он про ячейки говорил

Comment: Так содержимое как всех, так и каждой отдельно ячейки можно задать xpath запросом, из которых и состоит xsl. Пусть уточнит вопрос.

Comment: @nick_n_a, посмотрите по картинке. Он не знал как расставить эти ячейки, как там

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Вы все мне очень-очень помогли :) 
Извините, что вопрос был так по-дурацки поставлен, я дико паниковала и нервничала.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо! :)